# Sage Pay error on Opencart : "3067 : The ClientIPAddress is too long"

Tags: opencart, opayo

Some clients ( that with ipv6 ) are getting this error : "3067 : The ClientIPAddress is too long" after they buy a product from our website, an opencart 2.1.0.1. There is any solution or even better , if you have support for ipv6 !?

Best regards, Alex C

Answer (score 1):

Sage Pay doesn't support ipv6 at the moment. The best I can suggest is not submitting the Client IP if it is a v6 address....

Comment: How would you reccomend not subbmiting the ipv6 ?